# Code executes differently on Windows and Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm coding a simple game called [Jotto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jotto). A player tries to guess a secret five letter word; each letter is unique. After each 5-letter guess word you're told how many letters in the guess are also in the secret word. It's my first attempt at cross-platform development with Delphi. I've developed Windows apps in Delphi, and a little bit for Android with Flutter.

All the code executes as expected on Windows (32 bit), but not on Android (64 bit, SDK 25.2.5). No exceptions are raised, but the calculated number of correct guesses each turn are incorrect and unpredictable (i.e., the calculated result of `total` below is what's off). Running the code through the debugger shows local variables are incorrect sometimes, too.

Here are the relevant functions:

```
function TJotto.OccurrencesOfChar(const aWord, aChar: string): integer;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(aWord) do
    if aWord[i] = aChar then
      inc(result);
end;
```

and

```
function TJotto.MakeGuess(aGuessWord: string): string;
var
  i: integer;
  total: integer;
  wordToDisplay: string;
begin
  total := 0; // number of matches
  wordToDisplay := aGuessWord;
  // save copy of guess before deleting duplicate letters
  // because guess will be displayed
  // did user solve puzzle?
  if aGuessWord = FSecretWord then
    Exit('You did it! The word was ' + aGuessWord);
  // make sure all letters in aGuessWord are different
  // otherwise a guess like 'vexed' will say an E is present in FSecretWord twice
  for i := 5 downto 1 do
    if OccurrencesOfChar(aGuessWord, aGuessWord[i]) > 1 then
      Delete(aGuessWord, i, 1);
  // go through each letter in aGuessWord to see if it's in FSecretWord
  // keep a running total number of matches
  for i := 1 to Length(aGuessWord) do
    total := total + OccurrencesOfChar(FSecretWord, aGuessWord[i]);

  result := wordToDisplay + #9 + total.ToString;
end;
```

Comment: Character indexing in strings? You say: *Running the code through the debugger shows local variables are incorrect sometimes, too.* In what way exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: Previous to Delphi 10.4 the mobile compilers used by default 0-based indexing for strings. See [Zero-based strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Zero-based_strings_(Delphi)).

Use the `Low()` and `High()` intrinsic functions to iterate strings.

The irregularities you are seeing is because of indexing outside of the boundries of the string. When debugging, use overflow and range checking on to detect these kind of errors.

Your code will look like this:

```
function TJotto.OccurrencesOfChar(const aWord, aChar: string): integer;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := 0;
  for i := Low(aWord) to High(aWord) do
    if aWord[i] = aChar then
      inc(result);
end;
```

and

```
function TJotto.MakeGuess(aGuessWord: string): string;
var
  i: integer;
  total: integer;
  wordToDisplay: string;
begin
  total := 0; // number of matches
  wordToDisplay := aGuessWord;
  // save copy of guess before deleting duplicate letters
  // because guess will be displayed
  // did user solve puzzle?
  if aGuessWord = FSecretWord then
    Exit('You did it! The word was ' + aGuessWord);
  // make sure all letters in aGuessWord are different
  // otherwise a guess like 'vexed' will say an E is present in FSecretWord twice
  for i := High(aGuessWord) downto Low(aGuessWord) do
    if OccurrencesOfChar(aGuessWord, aGuessWord[i]) > 1 then 
      Delete(aGuessWord, i+1-Low(aGuessWord), 1); // Delete uses one-based array indexing even in platforms where the strings are zero-based.
  // go through each letter in aGuessWord to see if it's in FSecretWord
  // keep a running total number of matches
  for i := Low(aGuessWord) to High(aGuessWord) do
    total := total + OccurrencesOfChar(FSecretWord, aGuessWord[i]);

  result := wordToDisplay + #9 + total.ToString;
end;
```

Comment: This is a great answer. It solved my problem, it was succinct and clear, the code is there, and there's a link that helps me better understand what's happening. Thank you!

Comment: p.s. I had no idea about this change, even having read Embarcadero's instructions on setting up Android development. It could be problematic for others, too, because even beginners work with strings and indexes, and anyone starting with the 10.3 Community Edition and upgrading to 10.4 could have the same issue.

Comment: @AlC People had similar problems ever since Delphi introduced support for mobile platforms and with it Zero-based strings. That is why Delphi 10.4 uses One-based strings on all supported platforms to avoid such confusion. And yes One-based strings have been used in Delphi from the very beginning.